# How to set up JFrog CLI environment variables?

Tags: jfrog-cli

After reading [JFrogCLI-EnvironmentVariables](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/JFrog+CLI#JFrogCLI-EnvironmentVariables)

I would like to set `JFROG_CLI_OFFER_CONFIG` to false, but I have no idea.

I have tried `jfrog config JFROG_CLI_OFFER_CONFIG=false`, doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're on Linux or macOS you can do

```
CI=true jfrog rt ...
```

There is a sample [here](https://github.com/retgits/actions/blob/master/jfrog-cli-go/entrypoint.sh)

The other option you have on Linux and macOS is

```
export CI=true
jfrog rt ...
```

if you're on Windows you can do

```
set CI=true
jfrog rt ...
```

Comment: Update: you have to use CI=true as of JFrog CLI v2, the cli offer option does not work anymore.

Comment: What does the environment variable CI do? I can't find any documentation on JFrog's website about it.